# Streaming live .m3u8 from iOS to Chromecast

Tags: ios, video-streaming, chromecast

Following Google's documentation I can stream both .mp4 and .m3u8 on-demand streams to my Chromecast. When I try to Cast a live stream however the Cast icon fades away then reappears a second later.

Here is a working on-demand stream:

```
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation =
    [[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:
     @"http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8"
                                        streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeLive
                                       contentType:@"application/x-mpegURL"
                                          metadata:[self getMetadata]
                                    streamDuration:INFINITY
                                        customData:nil];
```

And here is a non-working live stream.

```
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation =
    [[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:
     @"http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/appleman.m3u8"
                                        streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeLive
                                       contentType:@"application/x-mpegURL"
                                          metadata:[self getMetadata]
                                    streamDuration:INFINITY
                                        customData:nil];
```

I've tested both of these in VLC to ensure the streams are actually active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second stream doesn't have CORS headers and that is a requirement for adaptive content on Chromecast. You can check that by calling `curl -v <url>` and then inspecting the headers:

```
$ curl -v http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/appleman.m3u8
*   Trying 8.253.43.126...
* Connected to vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net (8.253.43.126) port 80 (#0)
> GET /vevo/ch1/appleman.m3u8 HTTP/1.1
> Host: vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: max-age=2
< Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 15:44:12 GMT
< Content-Length: 427
< Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
< ETag: "6880298-1ab-51c1fc3e9da00"
< Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 23:07:20 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Server: Footprint Distributor V4.11
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Expires: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 15:44:14 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
```

If you do the same for the first one (that works), you'll get:

```
$ curl -v http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8
*   Trying 23.67.247.168...
* Connected to qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net (23.67.247.168) port 80 (#0)
> GET /1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8 HTTP/1.1
> Host: qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache
< ETag: "2b476bddec5a6410f01593dd3244bb86:1299516757"
< Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Mar 2011 16:52:37 GMT
< Content-Length: 940
< Expires: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 15:47:02 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 15:47:02 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: AKID=650047DEB61A8134C38CECC9EC836DF8;expires=Fri, 11-27-2015 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net
< Content-Type: application/x-mpegURL
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Set-Cookie: CLIENT_SESSION_COOKIE=csid=235AB97C3466663B398A6EC6DA38428C#ct=1448380022#master=sl.m3u8; path=/1010qwoeiuryfg; domain=qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net
< Set-Cookie: CLIENT_VIEWER_COOKIE=78FCBFC2DF7B7BD10F99EEC583042328;expires=Tue, 10-06-2014 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net
```

Note the presence of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the second one and not in the first one.

Comment: I have another stream that does have the Access-Control-allow-Origin: * marker, but still doesn't work.

Comment: If you have streams that are being served with CORS headers and are of supported formats and still don't play on Chromecast, you can open a ticket at https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list and include your receiver logs and the stream.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to double-double check to be sure it's not the stream's fault.

Comment: I found an NFL live stream that returns 

`< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *`
`< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *`
`< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS`
`< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

And it streams to the Chromecast no problem. the issue must be with the streams I've been given to test.

Thanks!